# How to method to change HTML background according to API result value?

Tags: javascript, html, background-image, weather, openweathermap

I create web application used HTML, CSS, JS (not jQuery) with openweathermap API.
I want to change the background depending on the weather.

But I've tried a lot, but it didn't work. The js file is one main.js file.

This is the JS code.

```
function displayResults(weather) {
  var city = document.querySelector(".city");
  city.innerHTML = weather.name + ", " + weather.sys.country;

  let now = new Date();
  let date = document.querySelector(".location .date");
  date.innerHTML = dateBuilder(now);

  let temp = document.querySelector(".current .temp");
  temp.innerHTML = Math.round(weather.main.temp - ChangeTemp).toFixed(0) + "°C";

  var weather_el = document.querySelector(".current .weather");
  weather_el.innerHTML = weather.weather[0].main;
  var weatherinfo = weather.weather[0].main;

  let hilow = document.querySelector(".hi-low");
  hilow.innerText =
    "Low and High Temp: " +
    Math.round(weather.main.temp_min - ChangeTemp) +
    " °C / " +
    Math.round(weather.main.temp_max - ChangeTemp) +
    " °C";
}

function backgroundChange(weather) {
  var imgs = document.getElementById("allbody");

  imgs.style.backgroundImage = "url(background.gif)";

  if (weatherinfo == Rain) {
    imgs.style.backgroundImage = "url(rain3.gif)";
  } else if (weatherinfo == Clouds) {
    imgs.style.backgroundImage = "url(cloud.gif)";
  } else if (weatherinfo == Clear) {
    imgs.style.backgroundImage = "url(sky3.gif)";
  } else {
    imgs.style.backgroundImage = "url(background.gif)";
  }
}
```

Not work function backgroundchange.

This is HTML code.

```
<div id='allbody' class="app" style="background-image: url(background.gif);">
```

```
<div>
    <header>
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="search-box" placeholder="Please enter the location."/>

    </header>

    <main>
        <section class="location">
            <div class="city">Location, Country</div>
            <div class="date">Today date info</div>
        </section>
        <div class="current">
            <div class="temp"><span>Temp (°C)</span></div>
            <div id="wdata" class="weather">Weather</div>
            <div class="hi-low">Low and High Temp</div>
        </div>
...
```

How can I change background image depending on the weather?

Thank you

Comment: Is `Rain`, `Clouds`, etc... a reference to a variable you haven't included in your code? Also nothing calls `backgroundChange`, so i'm not sure what code you're missing.

Comment: @Chase How to re-comment? sorry I do not know about this.
the Rain can Clouds from html result. So it's is not variable. then how can I do?

Comment: Not complete but just check. if complete, I will add here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of creating 'imgs' variable, better the use;
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(background.gif)";

```
function backgroundChange(weather) {
  if (weatherinfo == Rain) {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(rain3.gif)";
  } else if (weatherinfo == Clouds) {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(cloud.gif)";
  } else if (weatherinfo == Clear) {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(sky3.gif)";
  } else {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage= "url(background.gif)";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer.
But it doesn't work.
The background remains the same, and when searching for rainy areas, the background does not change.

Comment: weatherinfo is not defined in backgroundChange function.                                              function backgroundChange(weather) {
var weatherinfo = weather.weather[0].main;

Comment: I added the code, but not work... T.T sorry make confuse.

function backgroundChange (weather) {
  var weatherinfo = weather.weather [0] .main;
  if (weatherinfo == "Rain") {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('rain3.gif')";
  } else if (weatherinfo == "Clouds") {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('cloud.gif')";
  } else if (weatherinfo == "Clear") {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('sky3.gif')";
  } else {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage= "url('background.gif')";
  }
}

ofc I tried also removed "" too.

Comment: Sir, if I used PHP (NOT HTML) something different?

Comment: if I were you, I would prefer some CSS. You can check this link;                                     http://thenewcode.com/299/Dynamically-Resized-Backgrounds-With-CSS

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `imgs.style.backgroundImage = 'url(rain3.gif)';`, try     `imgs.style.backgroundImage = 'url('rain3.gif')';` with quotation marks around the image path too.

Comment: I tried it with double quotes and with quotes, but it still doesn't work.